# <td> has background image css

Tags: jquery

I am working on jquery. In my html I have many td and in which some td has background image.Like

```
<td background="images/bgblue.jpg">
```

So I want to find out which td has background as image or not. I want to change the image of td which have background="images/bgblue.jpg".

Thanks

Comment: As a side note, the `background` attribute is deprecated. Use CSS instead.

Comment: I have try many cases but all is failed. like i have used

Comment: Ctrl + F "images/bgblue.jpg"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try following way:

```
$(function(){
   $('td').each(function(){
     if($(this).attr('background')=='images/bgblue.jpg'){
       $(this).attr('background','images/bgwhite.jpg');
     }
   })
})
```

Comment: background is deprecated now\

Answer (score 0):

you can put class to every single one of td that has background. After that if you using jquery to set new background for that specific class

Comment: No, It is not possible to add class to every single one of td. So that i trying to solve it by jquery